# ES6 Computed Property Names in Python

Tags: python, dictionary, syntax

I'm trying to find an equivalent ES6 feature in Python.

In JS, I have something like this:

```js
let obj = {['composed' + objKey()]: true}
```

---

I want do be able to compose a dictionary key in a dict constructor in Python as well, something like:

```
MyClass.render(storyboard=dict([getAuthor()]=self.authorStoryData()))
```

`[getAuthor()]` should result in a dictionary key of the return value of that function. Or if it's variable, it's value, etc...

Is there anyway to do this in Python?

I've tried doing `dict=('%s' % (variable,)=self.content` but that threw errors.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Just like you use an object literal in JavaScript, you should use a dictionary literal in Python for this. This would be the exact equivalent in Python:

```
def objKey():
   return 'foo'

obj = {
    'composed' + objKey(): True
}

print(obj['composedfoo']) # True
```

Or in your actual case:

```
MyClass.render(storyboard={ getAuthor(): self.authorStoryData() })
```

---

As Jon highlights on the comments, the big difference between a JavaScript object literal and a Python dict literal is that Python’s behavior for the keys is basically JavaScript’s behavior with `[]` by default.

So to translate a `{ [expr]: value }` in JavaScript, you would write `{ expr: value }` in Python. But when you just write `{ key: value }` in JavaScript, you have to understand it’s essentially a `{ ['key']: value }` which makes it equivalent to `{ 'key': value }` in Python.

The reason why you need a string literal for string keys is simply because Python dictionaries can have almost arbitrary key *objects* and are not limited to string keys as JavaScript objects are.

Comment: Thank you. The following would still work as well yes? `MyClass.render(storyboard={ 'composed' + objKey(): self.authorStoryData() })`

Comment: Yeah, that works just the same. Though it might make sense to put the dictionary creation on its own line for readability reasons.

Comment: Basically whatever you want without the `[]` syntax. While `something` will be made a literal in JS in Python it will be the *value* of `something`...  and you have to make the literal explicit for literals...

Comment: Do you know of where I can find the documentation on this? I've checked [The Python Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/index.html) and the [Language Reference](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/index.html)

Comment: Syntactically, it’s defined [in the language reference](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#dictionary-displays), but explained in the [documentation for `dict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#mapping-types-dict). You have to keep in mind that keys in JavaScript objects can only be strings (or [symbols](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Symbol)), while dictionary keys can be almost any object, which makes Python require string literals when you want a string key.